# How to change layout of all category in magento to 1 column

Tags: category, category-listing

i have about 100 catgory in admin, is there way to change layout of all catgory to **1column**

i can do it from backend,but doing one by one will take too much time, is there way to do it quickly

[image]

i tried to do it from layout file but it is not working, below is my code of xml file , still is see products as 1 column-left

**Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */ 
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="banner_left" after="recentproductslider">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">banner_left</argument>
                </arguments>
           </block>
         </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="breadcrumbscategory" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbscategory.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.text" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom-list-page.phtml" after="breadcrumbscategory"/>
        </referenceContainer>   
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
          <move element="category.view.container" destination="page.top" before="-"/>
         <!-- <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="category.view.container" before="page.main.title"/> -->
         <move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-"/>
         <referenceContainer name="page.main.title" remove="1"/>
 <referenceContainer name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: yes you can do this from the layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe other modules rewrite that layout please check another module not conflict with it.

It is a bad habit to edit core files create the module and add the file to

```
app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

add below code to file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</page>
```

After this, please clear cache using below command :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Another Way**

The xml file you want to override is

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

So it should go in

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

***Example override***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

</page>
```

Comment: i am already following : Another Way , also no module in overriding that xml file, is there some different syntax as i am using magento 2.3

Comment: have you checked that there is  varnish or anything is enabled because some time due to cache it does not reflect changes or please enable pathing and check that you are overriding the same file. even it does not work then let me know

Answer (score 6):

For those which are searching this after Update to Magento >2.4.3
If the page builder (introduced in Magento CE 2.4.3) is active the page builder category layout has to get updated:

`app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_PageBuilder/page_layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forget to clear the cache after adding the file:

`bin/magento cache:clear`

Comment: Thank you so much. It is finally working !!

Answer (score 3):

Create or open file **app/design/frontend/[Theme-Package]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

Change the following line:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

to:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Comment: i have followed the same way but still not working in the M2.3.5 is there anything missing ? plz advise